# Mono XSP ignores <location> directive in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, mono, web-config, porting, xsp

I'm porting my `ASP.NET` application to `Mono`. I built it from `SVN trunk` under `Debian` 5.0.

I allow anonymous access to `Logout.aspx` and `styles.css` using `Web.config` directives:

```
<location path="Logout.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="styles.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

It works fine under `Visual Studio Web Server`, `IIS6` and `IIS7` but doesn't under `XSP2` 2.5.0.0. Are there any workarounds or ways to do the same task but differently?

I mean doesn't work - requesting redirects to `Login.aspx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug seems to have been fixed on the 9th of jan.
[See the details in mono's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=568441)

Unfortunately it does not seem to work on (sub)directories, so css and js directories are still not accessible after logging in.

Comment: Yea, you're right. We got success in the mailing list discussion. Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround, you can add multiple `<location>` elements to cover each subdirectory.